# try catch __finally use in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, try-catch-finally

Am I correct in thinking that this block of code:

```
try
    {
    Screen->Cursor = crHourGlass;
    try
        {
        throw Exception("error!");
        }
    catch(Exception& e)
        {
        Application->MessageBox(UnicodeString(e.Message).c_str(), L"Error", MB_OK);
        }
    }
__finally
    {
    Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
    }
```

Is in fact identical to this one and the **__finally** serves no purpose here because in both cases the **Screen->Cursor = crDefault** will be executed anyway?

```
Screen->Cursor = crHourGlass;
try
    {
    throw Exception("error!");
    }
catch(Exception& e)
    {
    Application->MessageBox(UnicodeString(e.Message).c_str(), L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first try be `__try` to match the Microsoft specific `__finally`?

Comment: @flatmouse: Not in C++Builder, no.  `try/__finally` is a valid combination.

Comment: FYI, `UnicodeString(e.Message).c_str()` is redundant, since `e.Message` is a `System::String` and `TApplicaton::MessageBox()` expects `System::Char*` values as input, so you can remove the type-cast: `Application->MessageBox(e.Message.c_str(), L"Error", MB_OK);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question - no, they are not *identical*, because there is a small possibility for the `crDefault` assignment to be skipped in the second version if something unexpected happens.  The `__finally` in the first version would typically handle that.

That being said, the alternative is to use an RAII container instead of `__finally`, eg:

```
class TUpdateScreenCursor
{
private:
    TCursor m_Original;

public:
    TUpdateScreenCursor(TCursor NewCursor)
    {
        m_Original = Screen->Cursor;
        Screen->Cursor = NewCursor;
    }

    ~TUpdateScreenCursor()
    {
        Screen->Cursor = m_Original;
    }
};
```

```
{
TUpdateScreenCursor sc(crHourGlass);
try
    {
    throw Exception("error!");
    }
catch (const Exception& e)
    {
    Application->MessageBox(e.Message.c_str(), _D("Error"), MB_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - It is a good reply but a bit of an overkill for this simple operation such as changing cursor type.

Answer (score 6):

No, because you are catching only exceptions of `Exception` type. If some other exception occurs then **Screen->Cursor = crDefault** will not be executed in the second version of code.

Comment: It also does not handle the possibility of `Application->MessageBox(UnicodeString(e.Message).c_str(), L"Error", MB_OK);` itself throwing another exception, such as a memory allocation error.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!